# Tasker Received text event not running / firing after recieveing sms

Tags: php, android, sms, sms-gateway, tasker

I created a tasker profile to forward recieved sms to a php script running on a remote server.
The event however is not firing / getting activated on receiving sms.
The following is the XML file exported from Tasker.

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="4.4u3m">
<Profile sr="prof6" ve="2">
<cdate>1417244856240</cdate>
<edate>1417247926509</edate>
<id>6</id>
<mid0>7</mid0>
<nme>ForwardSmsPhp</nme>
<Event sr="con0" ve="2">
<code>7</code>
<pri>0</pri>
<Int sr="arg0" val="2"/>
<Str sr="arg1" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg2" ve="3"/>
</Event>
</Profile>
<Task sr="task7">
<cdate>1417245005837</cdate>
<edate>1417246385348</edate>
<id>7</id>
<nme>PhpGet</nme>
<pri>10</pri>
<Action sr="act0" ve="6">
<code>118</code>
<Str sr="arg0" ve="3">10.16.35.177:8080</Str>
<Str sr="arg1" ve="3">messSms.php</Str>
<Str sr="arg2" ve="3">device=taskerMotog
smsrf=%SMSRF
smsrn=%SMSRN
smsrb=%SMSRB
smsrd=%SMSRD
smsrt=%SMSRT
time=%TIME</Str>
<Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
<Int sr="arg5" val="10"/>
<Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
<Int sr="arg8" val="0"/>
</Action>
</Task>
</TaskerData>
```

Neither am I able to forward sms to php script using the 'sms gateway' app on google play [Google Play Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I finally figured out the reason.
I had go-sms app installed on my mobile which was somehow preventing other applications from receiving 'recieved-sms' event.
I uninstalled go-sms and now Tasker is able to receive sms-event correctly.